# R "symbols": consistency in size between different plots

Tags: r, size, symbols

I am an R user and trying to display a set of xy graphs for aggregated data, in which each point is represented by a circle and the size of the circle is proportional to the number of individual data points in the aggregation.

The number of points in the aggregation is in the data frame W (first set of rows below):

```
   labels   x    DS0 DS1 DS2 DS3 DS4
1      NA 0.010   8   1   1   1   1
2   0.033 0.033   1   1   1   1   1
3      NA 0.050   2   1   1   1   1
4      NA 0.067   1   1   1   1   1
5      NA 0.100   8   6   2   2   2
6      NA 0.150   2   1   1   1   1
7      NA 0.167   1   1   1   1   1

# Figure 1
x11()
symbols(x=dobs[,2], y=dexp[,2], circles=W$DS1)  

# Figure 2
x11()
symbols(x=dobs[,2], y=dexp[,2], circles=W$DS1)
```

Based on the "symbols" R documentation, it appears that the circles will be formatted proportionally to the largest "weight" as a 1 inch radius circle. 
So in my example above, for DS1 my biggest circle corresponds to 8 for DS0, 6 for DS1, and 2 for DS2 etc.

But I would like to be able to compare graphs between them (and not just for these data), so I would like the sizes of my circles to be consistent between graphs. For example, my 1 inch circle would always correspond to a W value of 10 and the other weights would scale compared to this fixed value.

How do I do this using the symbols function?

Comment: Use`symbols(..., inches=FALSE)` so the circles are expressed in axis units.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean though by "expressed in axis units"? This is what they write in the R help also but this statement is not clear to me. For example, my xy axes are dimensionless, so I am not sure what the size of my final circle relates to.

Comment: Your x/y axes are not dimensionless. The symbols are plotted on a grid of points like any other plot like plot(1:10)

Comment: OK I get it. The "unit" is not a measurement unit such as "inches", but the default plot unit spacing, I see. Thank you